# Gradle: getting list of Maven repositories from downloaded POM

Tags: java, maven, gradle, repository, pom.xml

When trying to use

```
compile 'com.turn:ttorrent:1.4'
```

I get unresolved dependency net.sf.jargs.

POM of ttorent contains URL for external Maven repository:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-thirdparty-releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Thirdparty Releases</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

So adding that URL as repository explicitly solves that problem, but it is not Jedi way?
Can I say something to Gradle to make it doing such things implicitly?

Comment: Gradle is compatible with Maven and can use its repos.  See [Gradle Dependency Management](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Comment: Yes, but a question is about using Maven repositories, declared in POMs of dependencies. For instance, I have declared only mavenCentral, but ttorent (only for instance) depends on net.sf.jargs, which is not presented in mavenCentral, but in external repository which I mention in my question. I can define such repository explicitly, but it is Gradle work, does not it?

Answer (score 0):

Having repository declarations in published Maven POMs is discouraged, and Gradle will not honor them when resolving.